# What's the difference between public debt, national debt and government debt?

Tags: debt, government-debt

When it comes to non-private debt, I hear these three terms the most, but I am not sure if they're interchangeable or discernible. Also, are they recorded in the balance of payments? I'm guessing if they are, they'd be recorded in the transfers part of the current account and the capital and financial accounts.